# Parsing one table out of several tables contained in a html page using python

Tags: python, pandas, html-table, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a table inside an html page at [this link](https://www.360optimi.com/app/sec/resourceType/benchmarkGraph?resourceSubTypeId=5c9316b28e202b46c92ca518&resourceId=envdecAluminumWindowProfAl&profileId=Saray2016&benchmarkToShow=co2_cml&entityId=5e4eae0f619e783ceb5d0732&indicatorId=lcaForLevels-CO2&stateIdOfProject=), and I have yet to find a method ensuring I can point to the right table, as the page contains a few other tables as well - as shown on the image attached.

I have tried the simpler method, using pandas.read_html and let it figure it out, but this only returns the content of the top of the page (I am guessing), missing out everything else.

```
import pandas as pd
url='https://www.360optimi.com/app/sec/resourceType/benchmarkGraph?resourceSubTypeId=5c9316b28e202b46c92ca518&resourceId=envdecAluminumWindowProfAl&profileId=Saray2016&benchmarkToShow=co2_cml&entityId=5e4eae0f619e783ceb5d0732&indicatorId=lcaForLevels-CO2&stateIdOfProject='
tables = pd.read_html(url)
print(tables[0])
```

which returns:

```
            0         1         2
0     English  Français   Deutsch
1     Español     Suomi     Norsk
2  Nederlands   Svenska  Italiano
```

Any idea on how I can use the right html tags to point to the table of interest?

EDIT:
As some of you noted that login credentials are required for the web page (apologies), I have uploaded the html code [here](https://codepen.io/andreabotti/pen/abOJLeY).

[image: screenshot of web page with code inspected]

Comment: how are you logging in ?

Comment: Your page of interest asks for login credentials

Comment: @KarthickMohanraj and Datanovice apologies both, I have copied and pasted the html code into a codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken as input the html that you have provided. If you want to use this code on a url, just extract the html of that url before using this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

Your_input_html_string = str(html_code_of_your_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(Your_input_html_string) #Provide the html code of the url in string format as input over here

#The table id which you want to extract from this html is "resourceBenchmarkTable". So let's extract the html of this table alone from the entire html
extracted_table_html = str(soup.find_all("table",id="resourceBenchmarkTable"))

#Now, convert the specific extracted html of table into pandas dataframe
table_dataframe = pd.read_html(extracted_table_html)

print(table_dataframe)
```

**Output:** (Shows only first 5 rows to keep the answer short)

[image]

Comment: brilliant, thank you! How would I amend the code to read the `<a href>` tag and feed that into the Download EPD field/column?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have edited the code provided by @KarthickMohanraj, to implement the first step, i.e. reading a `html` file saved locally. The final code reads as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# opens html file saved locally
filepath = 'Aluminium_Profiles_profiles.html'
f = open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')

# reads html code as string
s = f.read()

# parse html string with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s) #Provide the html code of the url in string format as input over here

# The table id which you want to extract from this html is "resourceBenchmarkTable".
# So let's extract the html of this table alone from the entire html
extracted_table_html = str(soup.find_all("table",id="resourceBenchmarkTable"))

#Now, convert the specific extracted html of table into pandas dataframe
table_df = pd.read_html(extracted_table_html)[0]
```